# Entity code first migration try to drop old table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I added some entities to my context.And then i migrate them as a below with my tool

```
  using (var db = new TourismContext())
                {
                    if (db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
                        return;

                    var initializer = new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TourismContext, TourismContextConfiguration>();

                    initializer.InitializeDatabase(db);
//and other code.....
```

it drop tables which i removed them from my context.And it works.it is compatible.But after 20 minutes it says non compatible.it want to drop some tables but this tables are not existing
what should i do?

although i remove that tables from context and migrate it(migration tool drop that tables from database) why it want to drop them again and again?the tables that migration want to drop is not existing in database.because i migrate them so migration tool drop them.Where migration get that tables info to drop?

this is my __MigrationHistory

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [MigrationId]
      ,[Model]
      ,[ProductVersion]
      ,[CreatedOn]
  FROM [TOURISM_new1].[dbo].[__MigrationHistory]
```

there is no droping tables info here

here is my migration tool.There is two buton.one show scritp which will show executed script(script button) other is micration buton.it migrate

```
  private void MigrateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new TourismContext())
                {
                    if (db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
                        return;

                    var initializer = new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TourismContext, TourismContextConfiguration>();

                    initializer.InitializeDatabase(db);

                    foreach (Constants.SecurityFeatureIdentifier securityFeatureIdentifier in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Constants.SecurityFeatureIdentifier)))
                    {
                        if (db.SecurityFeatures.All(sf => sf.SecurityFeatureIdentifierID != (int)securityFeatureIdentifier))
                        {
                            db.SecurityFeatures.Add(new SecurityFeature { SecurityFeatureIdentifier = securityFeatureIdentifier });

                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }

                statusLabel.Text = "Compatible";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void ScriptButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var db = new TourismContext())
                {
                    if (db.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
                    return;

                    var migrator = new DbMigrator(new TourismContextConfiguration());

                    var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);

                    scriptControl.Text = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(null, null);

                    foreach (Constants.SecurityFeatureIdentifier securityFeatureIdentifier in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Constants.SecurityFeatureIdentifier)))
                    {
                        if (db.SecurityFeatures.All(sf => sf.SecurityFeatureIdentifierID != (int)securityFeatureIdentifier))
                        {
                            db.SecurityFeatures.Add(new SecurityFeature { SecurityFeatureIdentifier = securityFeatureIdentifier });

                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your database model in sync with your code first model. You could either comment out the obsolete code from the Up() method of the migration and do an update-database or you can remove the pending migration and do Add-Migration MyBaseline –IgnoreChanges with an update-database. Now you should be compatible until you change your model.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#option1

Comment: how can i sync?I don't have Up() method.Should i add Up() to context?

Comment: Up() methods are created automatically by the migration. You mentioned your migration was trying to drop non-existant tables Where are you seeing this?

Comment: i added migration tool buton.in that buton it shows script before execute it.i updated my question.you will see script generate  buton                       var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);

                    scriptControl.Text = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(null, null);